# how to concatenate a variable and a string in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'm new to terraform and trying to add a variable to a string,
Suppose, id = "abcde", host =~ ${id} + "id", should return abcdeid
what's the best way to achieve this in terraform?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a var called name and a suffix of -123

Host = “${var.name}-123”

Answer (score 4):

You can concatenate them directly or using [join](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html). For example:

```
variable "id" {
  default = "abcde"
}

output "output1" {
  value = "${var.id}id"
}

output "output2" {
  value = join("", [var.id, "id"])
}
```

which will give:

```
output1 = abcdeid
output2 = abcdeid
```